# Date Box on Form doPost returns as string, not Date Object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I've been searching for hours now, and I cannot seem to get an appropriate fix to this.

I have a form that has (among other things) a datebox. On submitting the form, and checking the value of the datebox, it comes out as a string, not a date object.

I need to use a form, and it needs to use the submit button, as I have a file uploader on it as well (which relies on these).

Relevant code below:

```
// Date Time Chooser
var dateLabel = app.createLabel('Date to Publish Article');
var dateBox = app.createDateBox().setName("date");
...
// Add a button to submit the info
var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('Submit');
...
// Sort the date and time
var date = e.parameters.date;
Logger.log(date);
Logger.log(typeof(date));
date.setHours(e.parameter.timeHour, e.parameter.timeMin);
```

Whenever not using a form, and using an ordinary button, it seems to pass as a date object just fine, but with the form and the submit button, it's a string.

Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

e.parameter return indeed always a string.

To convert it to a date object you could simply re-create a date like this :

```
  var d = e.parameter.date.split('-');// separate day,month and year
  var dateDate = new Date(d[0],d[1]-1,d[2],0,0,0,0);// month count from 0 >> -1 on d[1]
  Logger.log(d+'  '+dateDate); // check result in the logger

  // returned value example = 2013-07-31  -> date object construction =  new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

EDIT : to set hours , minutes and seconds you should use

```
date.setHours(Number(e.parameter.timeHour.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')), Number(e.parameter.timeMin.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''))); // use numbers as arguments and eliminate all other characters eventually present (for example if you use "11 hours" instead of simply "11"
```